# Qt4, QMenu addAction, connect function with arguments

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qpushbutton, qmenu

I would create a button with 3 choices that changes its text when you make a choice.

This solution works for me:

```
def swTrigger(self):
    self.setTrigger(self.ui.triggerButton,'Software')
def hwTrigger(self):
    self.setTrigger(self.ui.triggerButton,'Hardware')
def bothTrigger(self):
    self.setTrigger(self.ui.triggerButton,'Both')

def setTrigger(self,pushButton,value):
    pushButton.setText(value)
    #other actions

def uiConfig(self):     
    ##triggerbutton configuration 
    menu = QtGui.QMenu()
    menu.addAction('Software',self.swTrigger)
    menu.addAction('Hardware',self.hwTrigger)        
    menu.addAction('Both', self.bothTrigger)
    self.ui.triggerButton.setText("Software")   
    self.ui.triggerButton.setMenu(menu)
```

But I should like to avoid making a method for each menu item, because I would like to make dynamic menu entries.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use either `partial` or anonymous functions in combination with only one, parametrized, function to accomplish all tasks. Both versions (using `partial` and `lambda`) are shown in the example:

```
from functools import partial

def setTrigger(self, pushButton,value):
    pushButton.setText(value)
    #other actions

def uiConfig(self):     
    ##triggerbutton configuration 
    self.ui.triggerButton.setText("Software")
    self.ui.triggerButton.setMenu(menu)

    menu = QtGui.QMenu()
    menu.addAction('Software', partial(self.setTrigger, self.ui.triggerButton, 'Software'))
    menu.addAction('Hardware', lambda: self.setTrigger(self.ui.triggerButton, 'Hardware'))
```